# Dual Boot Linux Along side Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, swap

i am trying Ubuntu as my first linux time. Now as the steps of installation i had to shrink my HDD partitions, but in every single tutorial i find it written as unallocated space in my case it's written as free space (every single partition has it own space they are not all mixed up), now my questions.

- Is it Right to Install That way ? (the space is free not unallocated)
- Should I Create a New Partition for the Swap or it will just create it itself ? (and if i should i have 4GB RAM what is the needed size for this partition)
- in case i didn't like the OS can i uninstall using EasyBCD on windows 8.1 ?
- in the following picture there is a 32GB Partition. What is that ?

ps : i know this question may have been asked before but i can't find answer for my questions some of the questions may be a duplicates but i need answer for the rest. and i know this questions is not related to ubuntu but it's kinda general and if i am installing ubuntu i would be asking the same question, thank you.

[image]

Comment: Questions on Linux Mint should be asked on [unix.se].

Comment: @muru if you have read the post correctly it's general question sort of. and my questions has nothing to do with ubuntu or Mint. Answering the question instead of typing this comment would have been much helpful than your comment.

Comment: And posting on the correct site would have been much more helpful than either.

Comment: @muru and here i'm saying again i didn't know about this site. and my question is **GENERAL** . you know i can edit the post with replacing mint with ubuntu and would still the same question.

Comment: Then please do.

Comment: @muru done, can you answer now ? please ?

Comment: We still need more information. Since you can't upload a screenshot for some reason, can you boot a Ubuntu USB, choose "Try Ubuntu" and run `sudo parted -l` in a terminal so that we can get output in text, which you can then add to your post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51169/discussion-between-omar-alaa-and-muru).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it Right to Install That way ? (the space is free not unallocated)

The space is shown as free and not unallocated because it's in an extended partition. That's fine, Ubuntu can install to free space in an extended partition.

> Should I Create a New Partition for the Swap or it will just create it itself ? (and if i should i have 4GB RAM what is the needed size for this partition)

The installer creates any partitions it needs, including swap - you just need to provide it enough free (or unallocated) space.

> in case i didn't like the OS can i uninstall using EasyBCD on windows 8.1 ?

[How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

> in the following picture there is a 32GB Partition. What is that ?

Can't say. Could be some recovery partition created by the OEM.